# How to differentiate categorical and ordinal variables in regression analysis?

Tags: encoding, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, categorical-data

I am doing linear regression analysis on data concerned with houses. For now I have 23 features. Some of them are clearly ordinal (for example year, number of rooms, storey). Some features are categorical and I am confused on how to treat them when encoding to numeric format. I am hesitant on what encoding method to use: one-hot encoding (used for categorical) or just ordinal mapping (for ordinal data). 
I know that such categorical features as color, gender, district, nationality clearly must be coded using dummy coding. Also it is clear that such categorical feature as condition with possible values of *'old', 'renovated', 'new'* can be ordered and encoded as *1, 2, 3* respectively.

But I am not sure how to encode not quite obvious features. That features' nature is not instantly noticeable and to some extent can be attributed to ordinal data and categorical data at the same time. Let us look at the example:

```
Strongly Agree 
Agree 
Undecided 
Disagree 
Strongly Disagree
```

> It is from question:
>   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58818/can-ordinal-variables-be-used-as-predictor-for-linear-multiple-regression-analys

Author decided to encode them ordinally. Some adviced to use dummy coding. Not clear.
 
Another example (material):

```
Plastic
Wood    
Metal
Armored
```

From my perspective this data can be ordered and encoded ordinally as 1,2,3,4. Simply Armored more expensive than Metal. Metal more expensive than Wood and so on. But I saw a lecture on youtube where it is been said not to encode features ordinally just because you see some ascending or descending patterns. These patterns may be illusional and false.

Another example (internet connection type):

```
DSL
ADSL
SDSL
Cable
Broadband
```

Some of them quicker, some are slower than others but there is no "clear order". What to do with such 'unclear' categorical data.

How to differentiate categorical and ordinal data? Or I just have to encode ordinally only very plain ordinal variables such as 'condition' and keep the rest unclear variables as categorical and dummy code them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would say that ordinal variables is something that you can order and answers outside from your value set still make sense. good example is 'agree' / 'disagree'. you can map them to values 1-5 and even when you get 2.3 you kind of know what it means: it's a bit more than 'agree'. but it completely doesn't make sense with 'plastic'/'wood' - that's categorical. 
regarding internet connection type. it depends. if we are talking about speed and you could order those connections then it may make sense to treat it as ordinal. but if we are talking about e.g. modem type popularity than it's just a categorical variable

Answer (score 0):

When deciding on the type of encoding you want to perform on a categorical variable , don't look at the categorical variable as something that is independent from the rest of the variables which may seem obvious at the first but we may fall prey into doing it subconsiously. The reason why i said this is because when you decide on the type of encoding you want to perform,if you only decide on the basis of the variable alone then you can fall into the dilemna you mentioned where both types of encoding seems logical enough to be carried out. For instance just looking at the different categories present in the variable -
Plastic
Wood
Metal
Armored
it seems both type of encoding is logical depending on different perspectives.

but if you start to take into account other variables along with the main objective you will be able to decide more effectively which type of encoding you should use 'based' on the end goal.

so for the above example if your end goal is to predict quality of materials then ordinal encoding makes sense since your *END GOAL* necessitates some type of order which depicts quality .

but if your end goal for the above example is just predicting certain materials  to be used for a given equipment , then in that case nominal encoding makes sense since order doesnt matter here.

So you see how both encoding decisions are possible based on the end goal?! Therefore this decision is based on the END objective rather than looking at the variable as something independent from other factors.